# Globalization/CultureInfo in Android

Tags: java, android

It is possible to set the culture (for let's say en-Us) for the entire application? I know that in C# this is possible.

thanks advanced.

Comment: What do you mean with "culture" ?

Comment: i want to set for ex: the data to be in this format YYYY-MM-dd or the decimal numbers to use "." instead of ",", but this for the entire application. In c# i think the class is called cultureinfo.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think what you want is localization in android.

Just follow the link :

http://developer.android.com/resources/tutorials/localization/index.html

http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/localization.html

Comment: i have found a solution, it works, but will this work on any versions ? http://www.tutorialforandroid.com/2009/01/force-localize-application-on-android.html

Comment: this one will be used if you want to change the locale  of your application programtically not of the whole device from setting...hope you got...!!